# Why model getBulkProperties method is not working for some properties?

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I have used this method to get properties - **getBulkProperties(dbIds, options, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)** (refer this https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getbulkproperties-dbids-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback but it is not returning any property for some selected properties which I put it as propFilter.

**For eg.:**

```
 viewer.model.findProperty("GUID").then((dbids) => {
    viewer.model.getBulkProperties2(dbids, { propFilter: ["GUID"] ,categoryFilter:["Item"]}, (result) => {
    console.log(result));
    })
```

- In this dbids will be [] and also result is [].

But this https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/ to fetch all properties of the model.It will return elements having the selected properties.

For eg:

```
[ {
    "objectid": 1,
    "name": "House 4 - Rev1 (1)_V1.ifc",
    "properties": {
        "Item": {
            "Name": "House 4 - Rev1 (1)_V1.ifc",
            "Type": "File",
            "GUID": "e84c0e1c-fb65-5524-9276-61550e731ce4",
            "Icon": "File",
            "Hidden": "No",
            "Required": "No",
            "Material": "",
            "Unit": "Meters"
        }
    },
    "externalid": "a"
},{
    "objectid": 2,
    "name": "Project Number",
    "properties": {
        "Item": {
            "Name": "Project Number",
            "Type": "IFCPROJECT",
            "GUID": "6a3c29c3-b985-48d4-b6b4-104507a9c229",
            "Icon": "Collection",
            "Hidden": "No",
            "Required": "No",
            "Material": "",
            "Source File": "House 4 - Rev1 (1)_V1.ifc"
        },
        "IFC": {
            "NAME": "Project Number",
            "LONGNAME": "Project Name",
            "PHASE": "Project Status"
        },
        "IFCPERSON": {
            "GIVENNAME": "patel.vikas.bt15"
        },
        "IFCORGANIZATION": {
            "NAME": "Autodesk Revit 2022 (ENG)"
        },
        "IFCAPPLICATION": {
            "VERSION": "2022",
            "APPLICATIONFULLNAME": "Autodesk Revit 2022 (ENG)",
            "APPLICATIONIDENTIFIER": "Revit"
        },
        "IFCOWNERHISTORY": {
            "CHANGEACTION": "NOCHANGE",
            "CREATIONDATE": "1649310812"
        }
    },
    "externalid": "0"
}]
```

- Like above mentioned I am getting elements having **"GUID"** properties it means dbids will be (1,2,..) but in above example it doesn't return any dbids.

I have tried many times to fetch but every time it isn't working that's why I cant work further based the result I get(which is null).

As well as I am not able to fetch dbIds for specific property using this method **findProperty(propertyName)** or even if I am able to fetch ,dbIds will not have dbId which I want while that dbId exists in model.

Answer (score 0):

Not every design element may have the properties you're looking for. Below is an example IFC file loaded into the viewer. When I search for the `GUID` property on a *window* object, I can see that there's one, but when I search for the same property on a *body* object, there's no GUID.

[image]
[image]